# UITableViewCell stays highlighted after multiple selections of the same row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When selecting a row i deselect it.
And after selecting the same row twice the row stays highlighted.

Code:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Any Suggestions why is this happening?
Thanks

---

The problem is with a library (MaterialKit) i'm using for the cells.

Comment: do you modify highlihght cell style? i have just checked and it is working prety good for me with just deselectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Found the problem... i'm using a MaterialKit library.
And they change the style there.
Thanks